# Html Circular content animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of contents and I want to make it appear as a circle,just like this image [image: this image]
I can use css to make images corners round but I can not make it appear as a circle. I tried to use carousel css sliders but clould not find any thing. Can some one please help me find sth at lease similar so I can figure out how these kind f animations work?

for example look at this html

```
<div class="circle-menu">
<ul>
    <li><a class="spiritual" href="#">Spiritual</a></li>
    <li><a class="occupational" href="#">Occupational</a></li>
    <li><a class="emotional" href="#">Emotional</a></li>
    <li><a class="environmental" href="#">Environmental</a></li>
    <li><a class="intellectual" href="#">Intellectual</a></li>
    <li><a class="social" href="#">Social</a></li>
    <li><a class="physical" href="#">Physical</a></li>
</ul>
```

its css

```
    .circle-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

.circle-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 24em;
    height: 24em;
    border: dashed 2px #cccccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5em auto 7em;
}
.circle-menu a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  width: 8em; height: 8em;
  line-height:8em;
  margin: -3.5em;
  -moz-border-radius: 4em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4em;
  border-radius: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle-menu a.spiritual {background:#009cde;opacity: 0.6;}
.circle-menu a.occupational {background:#3a913f;opacity: 0.6;}
.circle-menu a.emotional {background:#fecd06;opacity: 0.6;}
.circle-menu a.environmental {background:#fa7f00;opacity: 0.6;}
.circle-menu a.intellectual {background:#ed2124;opacity: 0.6;}
.circle-menu a.social {background:#932683;opacity: 0.6;}
.circle-menu a.physical {background:#203864;opacity: 0.6;}

.circle-menu a.spiritual:hover {background:#009cde;opacity: 1.0;}
.circle-menu a.occupational:hover {background:#3a913f;opacity: 1.0;}
.circle-menu a.emotional:hover {background:#fecd06;opacity: 1.0;}
.circle-menu a.environmental:hover {background:#fa7f00;opacity: 1.0;}
.circle-menu a.intellectual:hover {background:#ed2124;opacity: 1.0;}
.circle-menu a.social:hover {background:#932683;opacity: 1.0;}
.circle-menu a.physical:hover {background:#203864;opacity: 1.0;}


 /* 360/7= 51 roughly so for 7 elements rotate the element every 51deg. 12em translate is half the container */
.circle-menu .spiritual { transform: rotate(51deg) translate(12em) rotate(-51deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(51deg) translate(12em) rotate(-51deg); -ms-transform: rotate(51deg) translate(12em) rotate(-51deg);}
.circle-menu .occupational { transform: rotate(102deg) translate(12em) rotate(-102deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(102deg) translate(12em) rotate(-102deg); -ms-transform: rotate(102deg) translate(12em) rotate(-102deg);}
.circle-menu .emotional { transform: rotate(153deg) translate(12em) rotate(-153deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(153deg) translate(12em) rotate(-153deg); -ms-transform: rotate(153deg) translate(12em) rotate(-153deg);}
.circle-menu .environmental { transform: rotate(204deg) translate(12em) rotate(-204deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(204deg) translate(12em) rotate(-204deg); -ms-transform:rotate(204deg) translate(12em) rotate(-204deg);}
.circle-menu .intellectual { transform: rotate(255deg) translate(12em) rotate(-255deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(255deg) translate(12em) rotate(-255deg); -ms-transform: rotate(255deg) translate(12em) rotate(-255eg);}
.circle-menu .social { transform: rotate(306deg) translate(12em) rotate(-306deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(306deg) translate(12em) rotate(-306deg); -ms-transform: rotate(306deg) translate(12em) rotate(-306deg);}
.circle-menu .physical { transform: rotate(357deg) translate(12em) rotate(-357deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(357deg) translate(12em) rotate(-357deg); -ms-transform: rotate(357deg) translate(12em) rotate(-357deg);}
```

its code-pan is available here
https://codepen.io/am2222/pen/XzqxNG

I want the above circle rotates by sweep of mouse or hand

thanks

Comment: Please provide a markup example. Also would you like it to rotate, slide or what?

Comment: @Maverick Hi, I provided a code-pan example,thanks

Comment: do you want to rotate your circle?

Comment: @SagarKodte yes,by users sweep to right and left or each 2000 milisecounds

Comment: @MajidHojati small circles or parent big circle path?

Comment: @SagarKodte small  circles must rotate around the big parent circle, the big parent circle is as a path which small ones rotates on it.

Comment: @MajidHojati ok..is it automatic continuously rotating or on any click or hover

Comment: @SagarKodte I want it to work with users sweep as I want to show webpage on mobile devices, could it be automatic too?

Comment: @MajidHojati you mean by holding mouse you want to rotate it? Yes. It can be automatic but it will forever rotate

Comment: @SagarKodte yes, in fact when user draws his finger each side it goes to next/previous circle(small ones).